# How to run a php script with arguments from a batch file?

Tags: php

I have a php script named `test.php`

in this file i have to pass one parameter using `$argv`.

i want to create window batch file that require one argument or parameter and pass that parameter in php script.

forexample in Windows Dos

```
test.bat hello123
```

so `hello123` is passed to `test.php` ($argv[1] is first parameter)

Can anyone help me to write batch file for this this kind of script?

Answer (score 2):

```
@c:/path/to/php.exe test.php %1
```